# MongoDB + Doctrine + Zend

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I'm integrating Zend and Doctrine 2 to work with MongoDB.
I'm using the quickstart skeleton.

Here is the Doctrine.php

```
<?php
use Doctrine\MongoDB\Connection;
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\DocumentManager;
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations;
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver;
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as ODM;
class Resource_Doctrine extends Zend_Application_Resource_ResourceAbstract
{   
    protected $_options = array();
    private $manager;

    public function __set($config, $null) {
        $this->_options = array(
                'connection' => array(
                        'dbname' => $config['connection']['dbname'],
                        ),
                'modelDir' => $config['modelDir'],
                'proxyDir' => $config['proxyDir'],
                'proxyNamespace' => $config['proxyNamespace'],
                'hydratorDir' => $config['proxyDir'],
                'hydratorNamespace' => $config['proxyNamespace'],
                'autoGenerateProxyClasses' => $config['autoGenerateProxyClasses']
        );
    }

    public function init()
    {   
        $zendConfig = $this->getOptions();
        if(!empty($zendConfig)) Zend_Registry::set('config', $zendConfig); 
        $options = Zend_Registry::get('config');
        $this->__set($options,null);
        $config = new \Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Configuration;
        $config->setDefaultDB($options['connection']['dbname']);
        $config->setProxyDir($this->_options['proxyDir']);
        $config->setProxyNamespace($this->_options['proxyNamespace']);
        $config->setHydratorDir($this->_options['hydratorDir']);
        $config->setHydratorNamespace($this->_options['hydratorNamespace']);
        $config->setMetadataDriverImpl(AnnotationDriver::create($this->_options['modelDir']));
        Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver::registerAnnotationClasses();
        $dm = DocumentManager::create(new Connection(), $config);

        return $dm;
    }
}
```

The class

```
<?php

use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\ClassMetadata;
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as ODM;

/** @ODM\Document */
class Application_Model_Guestbook
{
    /**
     * @ODM\Id
     */
    public $id;

    /** @ODM\String */
    public $email;

    /** @ODM\String */
    public $comment;

    /** @ODM\Date */
    public $created;

    public function setGuestbook($comment)
    {
        $this->email = $comment['email'];
        $this->comment = $comment['comment'];
        $this->created = date('d-m-Y H:i:s');
    }

    public function getGuestbook()
    {
        return $this;
    }
}
```

And the action

```
public function signAction()
    {
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        $this->getHelper('loadResource')->form('sign', 'Guestbook');
        $form    = new Application_Form_Guestbook();

        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            if ($form->isValid($request->getPost())) {
                $guestbook = new Application_Model_Guestbook;
                $guestbook->setGuestbook($form->getValues());
                try
                {
                    $this->em->persist($guestbook);
                    $this->em->flush($guestbook);
                    return $this->_helper->redirector('index');
                }
                catch (Exception $e)
                {
                    throw new Exception($e);
                }
            }
        }

        $this->view->form = $form;
    }
```

I'm geting the error: **Catchable fatal error: Argument 3 passed to Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Hydrator\HydratorFactory::hydrate() must be of the type array, null given, called in /home/gabiru/www/twitradar_mongo/library/Doctrine/ODM/MongoDB/UnitOfWork.php on line 2518**

I've searched and don't find any result of anyone with the same problem, anyone have any idea about it?

The 3rd argument is the variable $hint, and I don't know where the argument is set.

Comment: I solved the problem.
It was a permission problem on the proxies dir. If anyone whant to get a Zend + Doctrine2 + MongoDB quickstart here is mine => https://github.com/ogabiru/zend-doctrine2-mongodb-quickstart

Comment: Gabriel, I am having the exact problem just like you described and suspected that it wwas some kind of file/directory permission issue since this code works on my other machine as well as on our dev/production box. I tried to add mongodb user to the db directory but it did not make a lot of difference. It would incredibly helpful if you could elaborate a little bit on your solutions - specifically which proxy directory you gave permissions and which kind. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi Alex. I just give 777 permission to /application/proxies. Worked fine to me. I don't understand exactly what you did, so sorry me if it doesn't help, but I use the mongodb user just to validate the connection. The connection is like that: $options = array('username'=>'the_username','password'=>'the_password');$dm = DocumentManager::create(new Connection('localhost', $options), $config);
I don't use the mongodb user on the directory, only in the connection.

Comment: I got the same problem too when I've tried to save an record with a referenced field just with the ID. It works using the entire object.